# authentication of admin and retrieve specified filename from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

I want a code for authenticating an admin and thereafter if it is successful the admin must enter the filename so that the file contents like file id etc are retrieved from the database

Comment: You want a code? What prevents you to write one?

Comment: Please write from your side.We can assist in that if problem occur.

Comment: you didn't say you want a code and didn't show us what you've done - did you?

Answer (score 0):

```
THE HTML CODE:
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>

<style>
body{ background-image: url("wall0003.png");
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
background-position: top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}

</style>
</head>
 <body text="black" align="left">
        <form action="connectivity.php" onsubmit="post">
<br/>
<br/> <br/>
<br/> <br/> <br/> <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            User 
        <input type="text" name="userid"/>  <br/><br/>
            Pswd<input type="password" name="pswrd"/> <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/> 
        </form>
 <script language="javascript">
           function check(form) {
 /*function to check userid & password
                the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
                if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
 {
                    window.open('target.html')     //opens the target page while Id & password matches
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error Password or Username")  // displays error message
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

PHP CODE:
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'practice');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','admin');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); //connect to mysql
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); //select a mysql database
/*
$ID = $_POST['user'];
$Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/
function SignIn()
{
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if(!empty($_POST['user']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from login.html...is it empty or has some text?
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());//send mysql query to the database
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); //fetch a row result
    if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass']))
    {
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
        echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}

?>
```